# Парснинг сложного json, с неизвестным количеством вложений

Tags: java, json, парсер

в общем такая трабла... есть джсон строчка, которая получается из широко известного сайта. проблема в том, что в разных категориях она имеет множество разных уровней вложений, которые отловить простым for и if нереально. в связи с чем прошу помощи натолкнуть на верную тропу, чтобы на выходе получить ArrayList(map) с данными типа 
name=aaa
id=111
parent=xx и т.д.

```
    {
  "id": "204",
  "title": "Тип объявления",
  "type": "select",
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "1074",
      "title": "Продам",
      "params": [
        {
          "id": "532",
          "title": "Вид объекта",
          "type": "select",
          "values": [
            {
              "id": "5494",
              "title": "Гараж",
              "params": [
                {
                  "id": "783",
                  "title": "Тип гаража",
                  "multiple": true,
                  "type": "select",
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "id": "10991",
                      "title": "Железобетонный"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10993",
                      "title": "Кирпичный"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10995",
                      "title": "Металлический"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "5495",
              "title": "Машиноместо",
              "params": [
                {
                  "id": "781",
                  "title": "Тип машиноместа",
                  "multiple": true,
                  "type": "select",
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "id": "10983",
                      "title": "Многоуровневый паркинг"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10985",
                      "title": "Подземный паркинг"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10987",
                      "title": "Крытая стоянка"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10989",
                      "title": "Открытая стоянка"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "785",
          "title": "Охрана",
          "type": "select",
          "values": [
            {
              "id": "10997",
              "title": "Да"
            },
            {
              "id": "10999",
              "title": "Нет"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1075",
      "title": "Сдам",
      "params": [
        {
          "id": "563",
          "title": "Вид объекта",
          "type": "select",
          "values": [
            {
              "id": "5819",
              "title": "Гараж",
              "params": [
                {
                  "id": "784",
                  "title": "Тип гаража",
                  "multiple": true,
                  "type": "select",
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "id": "10992",
                      "title": "Железобетонный"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10994",
                      "title": "Кирпичный"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10996",
                      "title": "Металлический"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "5820",
              "title": "Машиноместо",
              "params": [
                {
                  "id": "782",
                  "title": "Тип машиноместа",
                  "multiple": true,
                  "type": "select",
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "id": "10984",
                      "title": "Многоуровневый паркинг"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10986",
                      "title": "Подземный паркинг"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10988",
                      "title": "Крытая стоянка"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "10990",
                      "title": "Открытая стоянка"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "786",
          "title": "Охрана",
          "type": "select",
          "values": [
            {
              "id": "10998",
              "title": "Да"
            },
            {
              "id": "11000",
              "title": "Нет"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1073",
      "title": "Куплю",
      "params": [
        {
          "id": "756",
          "title": "Вид объекта",
          "type": "select",
          "values": [
            {
              "id": "10897",
              "title": "Гараж"
            },
            {
              "id": "10898",
              "title": "Машиноместо"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1076",
      "title": "Сниму",
      "params": [
        {
          "id": "779",
          "title": "Вид объекта",
          "type": "select",
          "values": [
            {
              "id": "10981",
              "title": "Гараж"
            },
            {
              "id": "10982",
              "title": "Машиноместо"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: вам все узлы в json объекте нужно в список добавить или какие то определенные?

Comment: все узлы, чтоб потом их в другие запросы вставлять. дело в том, что в разных категориях может быть до 10 вложенных узлов... вот как бы это дело все перебрать для начала...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключите библиотеку `json`

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
 </dependency>
```

Примерный рекурсивный обход `json объекта` будет следующий:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonBodyStr);
List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
parser(jsonObject, "0", result);
for (Map<String, String> map : result)
        System.out.println(map.toString());


private static void parser(JSONObject jsonObject, String parentId, List<Map<String, String>> result) {
    String currentId = parentId;

    if (jsonObject.has("id") && jsonObject.has("title")) {
        Map<String, String> object = new HashMap<>();
        currentId = jsonObject.getString("id");
        object.put("id", currentId);
        object.put("name", jsonObject.getString("title"));
        object.put("parent", parentId);
        result.add(object);
    }

    for (String fieldName : jsonObject.keySet())
        if (jsonObject.get(fieldName) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(fieldName);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
                parser(array.getJSONObject(i), currentId, result);
        }
}
```

Comment: библа json не работает с моей json строкой.. пробую адаптировать к gson, но в нем нет аналога keyset...

Comment: А почему она не работает? Я на той строке, что в вопросе, тестировал, все работало.

Comment: пишет "Cannot resolve method keySet()". я работаю в idea. библиотеку подключил

Comment: вы вызываете метод keySet не на том типе объекта который требуется. Видимо у вас есть библиотека в которой тоже есть JSONObject класс, проверьте импорты.

Comment: http://s018.radikal.ru/i504/1608/8c/2b0657f4d372.jpg это все импорты... import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

Comment: импорты правильные. Тогда не понимаю, в чем может быть дело. ладно, там есть методы с похожей функциональностью, ими можно вытащить имена полей, например, `names()`, `keys()`, `getNames(Object object)`. Получите название полей и проитерируйтесь по ним.

Comment: Большое спасибо за наводку, с небольшими правками ваш код заработал!

Answer (score 0):

Адаптировал код [Артема Коновалова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10353/artem-konovalov) под использование GSON, теперь все работает! Спасибо большое

```
private static void parser(JsonObject jsonObject, String parentId, List<Map<String, String>> result){
        String currentId = parentId;

        if (jsonObject.has("id") && jsonObject.has("title")) {
            Map<String, String> object = new HashMap<>();
            currentId = jsonObject.get("id").toString();
            object.put("id", currentId);
            object.put("name", jsonObject.get("title").toString());
            object.put("parent", parentId);
            result.add(object);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> fieldName : jsonObject.entrySet())
            if (jsonObject.get(fieldName.getKey()) instanceof JsonArray) {
                JsonArray array = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray(fieldName.getKey());
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
                    parser(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject(), currentId, result);
            }
    }
```

на выходе имеем

```
{id="204", name="Тип объявления", parent=0}
{id="1074", name="Продам", parent="204"}
{id="532", name="Вид объекта", parent="1074"}
{id="5494", name="Гараж", parent="532"}
{id="783", name="Тип гаража", parent="5494"}
{id="10991", name="Железобетонный", parent="783"}
{id="10993", name="Кирпичный", parent="783"}
{id="10995", name="Металлический", parent="783"}
{id="5495", name="Машиноместо", parent="532"}
{id="781", name="Тип машиноместа", parent="5495"}
{id="10983", name="Многоуровневый паркинг", parent="781"}
{id="10985", name="Подземный паркинг", parent="781"}
{id="10987", name="Крытая стоянка", parent="781"}
{id="10989", name="Открытая стоянка", parent="781"}
{id="785", name="Охрана", parent="1074"}
{id="10997", name="Да", parent="785"}
{id="10999", name="Нет", parent="785"}
{id="1075", name="Сдам", parent="204"}
{id="563", name="Вид объекта", parent="1075"}
{id="5819", name="Гараж", parent="563"}
{id="784", name="Тип гаража", parent="5819"}
{id="10992", name="Железобетонный", parent="784"}
{id="10994", name="Кирпичный", parent="784"}
{id="10996", name="Металлический", parent="784"}
{id="5820", name="Машиноместо", parent="563"}
{id="782", name="Тип машиноместа", parent="5820"}
{id="10984", name="Многоуровневый паркинг", parent="782"}
{id="10986", name="Подземный паркинг", parent="782"}
{id="10988", name="Крытая стоянка", parent="782"}
{id="10990", name="Открытая стоянка", parent="782"}
{id="786", name="Охрана", parent="1075"}
{id="10998", name="Да", parent="786"}
{id="11000", name="Нет", parent="786"}
{id="1073", name="Куплю", parent="204"}
{id="756", name="Вид объекта", parent="1073"}
{id="10897", name="Гараж", parent="756"}
{id="10898", name="Машиноместо", parent="756"}
{id="1076", name="Сниму", parent="204"}
{id="779", name="Вид объекта", parent="1076"}
{id="10981", name="Гараж", parent="779"}
{id="10982", name="Машиноместо", parent="779"}
```

проблема неработающего кода была в Android Studio, под которой я запускал обычный java код.