# Как реализовать конвертацию многоуровневого JSON к одноуровневому list

Tags: c#, json, коллекции, json.net

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать приведение многоуровневого JSON к одномерному list с сохранением информации?
**Грубо говоря мне нужно записать названия категорий и ссылки в один list.**

У меня есть тестовый проект, получил от него вот такой JSON:

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "title": "Масла и автохимия",
  "link": "/catalogs2/4",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 41,
      "title": "Масла",
      "link": "/catalogs2/41",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 211,
          "title": "гидравлические",
          "link": "/catalogs2/211"
        },
        {
          "id": 212,
          "title": "моторные",
          "link": "/catalogs2/212"
        },
        {
          "id": 215,
          "title": "трансмиссионные",
          "link": "/catalogs2/215"
        },
        {
          "id": 75,
          "title": "амортизационные",
          "link": "/catalogs2/fluids-amortization"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 42,
      "title": "Жидкости",
      "link": "/catalogs2/42",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 216,
          "title": "AdBlue",
          "link": "/catalogs2/216"
        },
        {
          "id": 217,
          "title": "охлаждающие",
          "link": "/catalogs2/217"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 43,
      "title": "Присадки",
      "link": "/catalogs2/43",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 220,
          "title": "в масла",
          "link": "/catalogs2/220"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 255,
      "title": "Смазки",
      "link": "/catalogs2/255"
    },
    {
      "id": 281,
      "title": "Уход и очистка",
      "link": "/catalogs2/281"
    }
  ]
}
```

Сейчас я это реализовал тремя циклами, так как максимальная вложенность равна трем. Но меня все волнует вопрос, а что если это значение увеличится, неправильно делать так топорно.

Пришел к решению, что нужно через рекурсию. Но так и не понял как реализовать.

В VS для десериализации JSON я создал класс.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Child
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("children")]
    public Child[] Children { get; set; }
}
```

Результат должен быть таким `list<string>`:

```
"Масла и автохимия" || "/catalog/4"
"Масла" || "/catalogs2/41"
"гидравлические" || "/catalog/211"
... [сокращение] ...
"Жидкости" || "/catalog/42"
"AdBlue" || "/catalog/216"
... [и т.д.] ...
```

[Нашел вот такое решение, но не понимать как его адаптировать под мою задачу на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/558054/493051)

Comment: Используйте библиотеку [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). В вашем коде нужно будет просто передать строку json в метод: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Child>(jsonAsString)`.

Comment: @Aarnihauta Да, вы правы. Я уже использую в своем решении эту библиотеку и данный метод.
Но, к сожалению, чтобы сделать как описано в моём вопросе, нужно перебрать данную коллекцию тремя циклами. Это не подходит, так как вложенность может быть динамической.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Есть вариант решения вашей задачи через рекурсию. Пока не смог придумать, как избавиться здесь от рекурсии:

```
public static string Format(string json)
{
    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Child>(json);
    var items = Unwrap(root);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"\"{item.Title}\" || \"{item.Link}\"");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

private static List<Child> Unwrap(Child parent)
{
    var result = new List<Child> {parent};

    if (parent.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (var child in parent.Children)
        {
            result.AddRange(Unwrap(child));
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Метод `Format()` на вход принимает ваш JSON и на выходе возвращает строку, которую вы ожидаете увидеть.

Comment: Спасибо вам. Вы открыли мне глаза.  
Мне как раз с помощью рекурсии и нужно было.  
Я предложил небольшие правки, так как мне нужно на выходе не строка, а коллекция `list`.  
Я вам безмерно благодарен.